# how to grant permission to my applet

Tags: java, security, applet

My applet gave me an access denied (`java.net.socket.Persmission`) ERROR just when I changed URL from `localhost:8090/Project/map.jsp` to `10.1.1.27:8090/Project/map.jsp` or when I tried to connect from another computer.

so I looked for a solution and I found that I need to grant my applet Permission in file named java.policy at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40\lib\security`
like this:
 `<< grant { permission java.security.AllPermission;}; >>`
but it didn't work for me and I want to know why and how to specific my own applet with those permission.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what are using your applet for?

Comment: it's connected to a DB using a servlet and change the info to a graphic (position of trucks in the company's parking)

Comment: Is there a hard requirement to run your "application" in a browser? Because if not - you might simple **not** use an applet.

Comment: I didn't understand what did u mean by requirement ( hardware or codes)

Comment: I mean: what is the reason that you want to use Java applets?

Comment: The applet will need to be digitally signed prior to deployment so you might as well add signing to the build script.  Editing policy files is pointless.  BTW - does the applet open a socket connection to it's own server (the one that supplied the applet to the user)?

Answer (score 0):

Go to command line and type policytool it will open editor to create policy file now add permissions on policy file whatever you like and save file with name .java.policy in user home directory. It will be enough to provide permission to your applet.

Comment: can explain more because this my 1st time with applets

Comment: It is simple as I mentioned in steps, Just run policytool and add permission there is lot of permission when you run the tool you will get understand they are simple. finally use file menu save the policy in file just to remember that your file name should be .java.policy and location should be your user home directory.

Comment: If you want to grant all permission than copy this text in your policy file -     grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

Comment: I knew this one, but I want to specify my own applet by this code not all applets when I added < grant codebase"http://localhost:8090/ProjectStage/applet.jar" { permission java.security.AllPermission; } it didn't work for me